# external HDDs cannot copy files out

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, file-transfer

I have 3 different external HDD, 1Tb, exFAT format (for Mac and PC). They all developed the same problem: I cannot copy some files from them. The copying speed just drops to 0 on them and that is it. However, I can still play the files (they are mp4 video), sometimes flawlessly, sometimes with little pauses. 
tried chkdsk with /f - no effect, tried xcopy with /j (no buffering for big files, they are big, some several Gb) - cannot copy either.

Tried putting them directly in PC (I have enough SATA ports there), same problem.

HDDs are SATA II, enclosure USB2

2 LaCie and WD

My guess is some blocks become/behave unhealthy, but why on all 3 of them?

Have anybody experienced the same?

Comment: what do the disks SMART stats show about their health? Also, how long are the file names in question? do any have a full path length in excess of 256 characters?

Comment: Does this happen only on one of your computers or on all of them? I'd recommend you to test the external drives using their brand-specific diagnostic tool or [test for defects through the Disk Utility in Mac OS X](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=HHhsnY). You can use [WD's Data LifeGuard for Windows](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=lmFrxx) for your WD drive. Another thing you should try is updating the USB hub controller drivers on your computers from their manufacturer's website. Keep me posted with the troubleshooting!

Comment: Thanks for replies guys. SMART shows bad disks - all of them! I guess it is my luck, weird though. All disks developed bad blocks. I had to use dd and ddrescue to salvage data from them. One of LaCies died completely, was not able to mount it, was showing up as RAW un-formatted media - CnW recovery tool was able to rescue files from it. It took me days, literally, to do it. Luckily it was video recs - it is not noticeable, only sometimes, but not too horrible.