# New external USB HDD cannot copy big files and develops bad blocks

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, bad-blocks

I had an issue with external HDD not being able copy out big files but thought it was due to the bad blocks that they had ([here is that question](https://superuser.com/questions/1007731/external-hdds-cannot-copy-files-out)).

But now I have brand new 5Tb that I am trying to use and it fails to copy big (3-4Gb video files). It started clicking after/during copy and now chkdsk reports bad blocks!

I found a lot of posts about problems copying big files to/from USB HDD in Windows - but not about ruining HDD while doing it. WTH.

Anybody had similar issues?

**UPDATE:** Disk became unrecornizable. Disk is seagate, I downloaded and run seatools: Short Drive Self Test is 100% OK, all others fail with 0% done. Anybody has experience with that?

Another symptoms: Windows7 disk manager sees the disk as not initialized - offers initializing it to be able to use it, Windows8 disk manager does not see it at all (u can still see it in device manager).

When I plug it in it spins up tries/clicks 2 times and that is it, no other sounds(spin ups/downs) even when trying tests in Seatools.

Comment: If the drive is clicking that indicates a hardware failure.

Comment: check the SMART stats. At least one out of 7 new hard disks I end up with were DOA. BadBlocks are not caused by file operations; they were already damaged, but the system didn't know that yet, until it tried to perform an operation in that block and encountered an error.

Comment: Disk is seagate, I downloaded and run seatools: Short Drive Self Test is 100% OK, all others fail with 0% done. Anybody has experience with that?

Comment: I do. I had a similar experience with WD Elememts 1TB HDD, but only after one month of use.

Comment: Short SMART tests only test a small amount of the disks surface. a Long/Extended test covers the whole disk surface, so bad it is much more likely to find new bad blocks. check you stats again, with particular emphasis on Reallocated Sector Count, Current Pending Sector Count, and Raw Read Error rate. Anyway at this point, your disk is pretty clear that it is not working correctly, so plan to replace it.